# How to add firebase to Vuepress?

Tags: firebase, vuepress

I'm trying to add firebase code into Vuepress so I can embed a simple review app into all the Vuepress pages. Wondering how to do that?

```

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "asdf",
    authDomain: "adsf-9e0b6.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://asdf-9e0b6.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "sadf-9e0b6",
    storageBucket: "adsf-9e0b6.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "asdf"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

```

Comment: You would probably be better of including it in the `enchanceApp.js` file and installing it with NPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this in the `config.js` within the **head** array. Note that this adds `firebase-app` (core), `firebase-auth`, `firestore`,  and `cloud functions` as I'm using 4 modules in my project.

NOTE that I'm also initializing both `firebase` and `firestore` in here. So I get firestore as a global variable.

When firebase loads, all these will be hoisted to the head section of the app.

```
 head: [

    [
      "script",
      {
        src: "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-app.js"
      }
    ],

    [
      "script",
      {
        src: "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-auth.js"
      }
    ],

    [
      "script",
      {
        src: "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-firestore.js"
      }
    ],

    [
      "script",
      {
        src: "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-functions.js"
      }
    ],

    [
      "script",
      {},
      `var config = {
        apiKey: "apikey",
        authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "appname",
        storageBucket: "appname.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "12345"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      const firestore = firebase.firestore();
      const settings = { /* your settings... */
          timestampsInSnapshots: true
      };
      firestore.settings(settings);`
    ],
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors when Vuepress builds the site, you need to run the Firebase initialization only client side.

Google moved to a more generic model for configuration. It suggests using includes which automatically fetch the configuration parameters.

My answer also include the enabling of Firebase analytics.

In `config.js` `head` array:

```js
    ["script", {src:"/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"}],
    ["script", {src:"/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"}],
```

In `enhanceApp.js`

```js
function loadJavaScriptAsync(file, onload) {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = file;
  script.onload = onload;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

export default ({
  Vue, // the version of Vue being used in the VuePress app
  options, // the options for the root Vue instance
  router, // the router instance for the app
  siteData, // site metadata
  isServer
}) => {
  if (!isServer && !window.location.href.startsWith("http://localhost")) {
    loadJavaScriptAsync("/__/firebase/init.js", () => {
      firebase.analytics();
      router.afterEach(() => {
        firebase.analytics().logEvent("page_view")
      });
    })
  }
}
```